# how to find the diff of two sorted files (compare line by lilne)

Tags: diff

file 1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
.
.
z
```

file2:

```
d
g
k
```

how do I find the data exists in 1 but not 2.

Comment: using which language? Please specify...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a utility that already does that:

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

use unix [comm](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_comm.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX standard [comm utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) also does this.

Answer (score -1):

Use a program that does exactly that. i'm using kdiff3. for windows i think there is winmerge